# Get JSON API data to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get data from JSON API and display in a html. I'm using ipinfo.io API to get city location by IP address and openweathermap API to get current weather. But the code doesn't work, did i miss something ?

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks in advance.

```
<div class="section no-pad-bot">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row center">
            <div id="putWeather" class="card-panel hoverable card-container">
            <!-- text from JSON here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

          var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
          var units = "&units=metric";
          var appid = "&APPID=abcdefgh12345678"
          var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

          var getIP = 'https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

          $.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
              var getCity = location.city;  //get city from IP

              $.getJSON(api + getCity + units+ appid + cb, function( data ) {
                $('#putWeather').html(Math.round(data.main.temp)+ ' degrees Celcius');
            });
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not authorized to make this request. If you look at Chrome's networking tab, you'll see the following `401 Unauthorized` error:

> SSL access is restricted to paid plans. See http://ipinfo.io/pricing
>   for more details, or contact us via http://ipinfo.io/contact

Comment: When i check networking tab, i got this error `GET http://ipinfo.io/json/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`. Is it because the browser or the API ? should i change to other API ?

Comment: Change your `api` and `getIP` variable values to begin with `https` instead of `http` and you'll see the same error in my answer.

Comment: Oh the error was solved, it was caused by Adblock. But my code still didn't get the data, i've already changed the the API (see above code),there is no error anymore in console, what am i miss ?